# Gcc - Undefined reference but library contains matching symbol

Tags: c++, linux, g++

i have tried to link a programm of mine with the [libmodbus](https://github.com/rscada/libmodbus) opensource lib. After some trouble with automake, i finally managed to compile it.

But now I get a undefined reference error from gcc, when I use one of the functions the library provides in my own programm:

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `modbus_udp_init(char*, int, __modbus_udp_handle*)'
collect2: Fehler: ld gab 1 als Ende-Status zurück
```

From my point of view, the arguments of gcc to compile my project are correct:

```
g++ -v -I ../libmodbus/modbus -o main main.cpp -L../libmodbus/modbus/.libs/ -lmodbus
```

I checked with `nm` if the function is really in that library, but everything looks fine for me (I have deleted some parts from the output, to prevent the output from getting too big):

```
$ nm ../libmodbus/modbus/.libs/libmodbus.a 

modbus.o:
0000000000000590 T crc16
                 U free
                 U malloc
                 U memcpy
0000000000000b40 T modbus_diagnostics
0000000000000d90 T modbus_error_get_exception_code
0000000000000100 C modbus_error_str
0000000000000cf0 T modbus_exception
[...]

modbus-udp.o:
                 U bcopy
                 U close
                 U __errno_location
                 U gethostbyname
                 U modbus_error_str
                 U modbus_tcp_frame_pack
                 U modbus_tcp_frame_parse
0000000000000000 T modbus_udp_close
0000000000000030 T modbus_udp_init
0000000000000220 T modbus_udp_recv
0000000000000190 T modbus_udp_send
0000000000000010 r __PRETTY_FUNCTION__.4582
0000000000000000 r __PRETTY_FUNCTION__.4592
                 U recvfrom
                 U sendto
                 U setsockopt
                 U snprintf
                 U socket
                 U strerror

modbus-tcp.o:
[...]


modbus-serial.o:
[...]
```

Does someone have an idea why gcc can't resolve the symbol?

Comment: Is `modbus_udp_init` declared as `extern "C"` (or is `libmodbus` a C++ library)?

Comment: You don't show enough information for me to be certain, but I suspect you have made one of the oldest errors in the book: The `-lmodbus` option needs to go AFTER all of the object files.  (All the other options can stay where they are.)  This is because an `-l` option means "search this library for all unresolved symbols *so far*, working left to right on the command line".

Comment: And I think @noloader may *also* be correct in diagnosing a missing `extern "C"`.  (This would be a bug in the library, but can be worked around in your code by wrapping an appropriate set of `#include`s in `extern C {` ... `}`.)

Comment: @noloader: You were right, the ´extern "C"´ was missing... Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noloader suggested, i missed adding `extern "C"` as libmodbus is a C-library. I edited my source:

```
extern "C" {
    #include <modbus.h>
    #include <modbus-udp.h>
}
```

Now it compiles fine. Thank you!